# Text alignment doesnt work on mobile [CSS]

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a weird problem with text alignment which I never had before.

On this app: https://damdafayton-countries.herokuapp.com/
two sections of text doesn't get aligned to middle in the mobile browser.

[Here is desktop view.](https://damdafayton-countries.herokuapp.com/problem/neighbor-desktop.png)

[And here is the view from android virtual device.](https://damdafayton-countries.herokuapp.com/problem/neighbor-mobile.png) I got the same view on mobile phone.

To amend the UI I did adjust the `line-height` for the above text and did `vertical-align:sub`. This fixed the view on mobile but as you can see its not in the middle in desktop browser.

But the text below doesn't respond to neither `line-height` nor `vertical-align`.

I have never experienced such trouble with text alignment before and I almost did zero progress. Probably I am missing something vital.

First text

```
<div className="text-center">
<NavLink to="/" className="text-white hover-1">HOME</NavLink>
</div>
```

Second text

```
<div className="bg-info py-2">
  <h2 className="fs-6 px-2 mb-0 flex-grow-1">
    {title}
  </h2>
</div>
```

Edit: I have reversed the amendments; currently desktop view it how its supposed to be and on mobile both texts are not aligned.

Comment: Please post the code to your question. If you fix your app link, this question will be useless to future visitors.

Comment: your app  link is not  working (failure to fetch in your api.js file), so without some more context of your HTML it's a little hard to assist you.

Comment: It works when I try, could you check again pls? Maybe it coincided with my update.

Comment: Ah, I see. my ublock origin was stopping the request from going through for some reason.

Comment: Looks  Good to me? Don't notice any discrepancies with the spacing between desktop / the mobile emulator on my end.
https://imgur.com/a/2eWPXGu

Comment: Problem isnt apparent on emulator. It can be seen on real mobile phone or android virtual device.

Comment: My mobile screenshot is not from emulator. Its inspector for AVD. https://ibb.co/7Sf9CbK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure I understood your problem but if your are talking about the titles that are not vertical align it's because of your font "Gill,sans-serif"
Sometimes some fonts change the vertical orgin point

Comment: Yeah seems "Gill" font was distorting the alignment. Now its fixed. It was very annoying problem. Thanks a lot!